# rails tutorial chapter 13.4.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

i am newbie and learning rails
i have setup my aws account, created a bucket and IAM. I have also attached the required policies to my IAM.
However i am unable to upload picture.

```
if Rails.env.production?
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

config.fog_credentials = {
  # Configuration for Amazon S3
  :provider              => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
  :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
}
config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
 end
end



class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]

if Rails.env.production?
 storage:fog
else
 storage:file
end

def store_dir
 "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end

end
```

these are my logs:
[image]

edited , this is my micropost_controller.rb

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:destroy]

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

   private

    def micropost_params
     params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
   end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

thx

Comment: it looks like a policy issue on AWS. When I followed that tutorial I remember I created a group, assigned the required policies to it, and then added a specific user (used by the app) to the group. Anyway, pls add to your question the `microposts_controller.rb` so we can inspect the create action.

Comment: Also, depending on which AWS region you are using, you might need to add `:region => ENV['S3_REGION']` to your `carrier_wave.rb` initializer, inside `config.fog_credentials` hash.

Comment: Your controller looks good. Have you tried adding the region config to fog_credentials?

Comment: yup added , still not working though

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem , it was at heroku . My config vars S3_BUCKET was actually S3__BUCKET , silly me . THanks dave